Unable to Authenticate Sector 0 with Mifare Classic Key using React Native NFC Manager
I am working on a React Native project to read NFC Mifare Classic cards using the react-native-nfc-manager library. My goal is to authenticate and read data from sector 0 using the default Mifare Classic key FFFFFFFFFFFF. However, even though I know the key is correct (it works with other apps like Mifare Classic Tool and my previous Java app), my React Native implementation consistently fails to authenticate.
What I’ve Tried
Here is my implementation for sector 0 reading:
NFCManagerService.ts
import NfcManager, { NfcTech } from 'react-native-nfc-manager';

class NFCManagerService {
    private static instance: NFCManagerService;

    private readonly CMD = {
        AUTH_A: 0x60, // Authenticate with Key A
        READ: 0x30,   // Read block
    };

    private constructor() { }

    public static getInstance(): NFCManagerService {
        if (!NFCManagerService.instance) {
            NFCManagerService.instance = new NFCManagerService();
        }
        return NFCManagerService.instance;
    }

    public async readSectorZero(logCallback: (message: string) => void): Promise<void> {
        try {
            logCallback('Initializing NFC...');
            await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.MifareClassic);
            logCallback('NFC initialized.');

            const tag = await NfcManager.getTag();
            if (!tag) {
                throw new Error('No tag detected.');
            }
            logCallback(`Tag detected: ${tag.id}`);

            const key = [0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff];
            const keyHex = key.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
            logCallback(`Attempting Auth A Sector 0 with key: ${keyHex}`);

            if (await this.authenticateSector(0, key)) {
                logCallback(`✓ Auth A Sector 0 succeeded with key: ${keyHex}`);

                const data = await this.readBlock(0);
                if (data) {
                    logCallback(`Data from Block 0: ${Array.from(data).map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(' ')}`);
                } else {
                    logCallback('Failed to read data from Block 0.');
                }
            } else {
                logCallback(`✗ Auth A Sector 0 failed with key: ${keyHex}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            logCallback(`Error: ${error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error'}`);
        } finally {
            await NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
            logCallback('NFC released.');
        }
    }

    private async authenticateSector(sector: number, key: number[]): Promise<boolean> {
        try {
            const authCommand = [this.CMD.AUTH_A, sector * 4, ...key];
            await NfcManager.transceive(authCommand);
            return true;
        } catch {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async readBlock(blockIndex: number): Promise<Uint8Array | null> {
        try {
            const readCommand = [this.CMD.READ, blockIndex];
            const response = await NfcManager.transceive(readCommand);
            return new Uint8Array(response);
        } catch {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

export default NFCManagerService;

ReaderScreen.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import NFCManagerService from '../services/NFCManagerService';

const ReaderScreen = () => {
    const [logs, setLogs] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [isReading, setIsReading] = useState(false);

    const addLog = (message: string) => {
        setLogs(prevLogs => [...prevLogs, message]);
    };

    const handleReadSectorZero = async () => {
        setIsReading(true);
        setLogs([]);
        try {
            const nfcService = NFCManagerService.getInstance();
            await nfcService.readSectorZero(addLog);
        } catch {
            addLog('Error reading the badge.');
        } finally {
            setIsReading(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
                title={isReading ? 'Reading...' : 'Read Sector 0'}
                onPress={handleReadSectorZero}
                disabled={isReading}
            />
            <ScrollView style={styles.logContainer}>
                {logs.map((log, index) => (
                    <Text key={index} style={styles.logText}>{log}</Text>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
    },
    logContainer: {
        marginTop: 20,
        maxHeight: 400,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 8,
    },
    logText: {
        fontSize: 14,
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});

export default ReaderScreen;


The Issue:
I can detect the card and send commands using NfcManager.transceive.
The card is a blank Mifare Classic 1K, and sector 0 should be readable with the default key FFFFFFFFFFFF.
The same card and key work perfectly with the Mifare Classic Tool app.
Here is a log from my app when attempting to authenticate:

According to NXP's documentation for NFC MIFARE Classic, block 0 of sector 0 contains Manufacturer Data, so you will need to start reading from block 1 for sector 0.
